# how to set file permission 0555 using ftp_chmod in php

Tags: php, ftp, chmod

How to set file permission 0555 using ftp_chmod?

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "example.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "user", "password");

$file = "path/index.php";
ftp_chmod($ftp_conn, 0555, $file)
?>
```

using this script i can not change file permission to 0555!!  using this script i can change 0666,0777 but i cant not change to 0555

output of above script is 0655!!

Comment: please take a look at the permissions the ftp-user 'user' you are using may be setting to a file...

Comment: i can't understand you comment please reply in  detail @RichardBernards

Comment: you are using the user 'user' with password 'password' to connect to the ftp-server. On the ftp-server, does this user have the required permissions to set a file to 0555 ?

Comment: Please also check if the result of ftp_chmod() is false (if so, the operation could not be performed)

Comment: i want to set index.php redy only for all

Comment: result of ftp_chmod() is true